# What amount of humor is acceptable?

Tags: discussion

Like usual, the title sums up my inquiry. Most of humorous posts seem to have informational value and comedic value, so I think they should be welcomed. I have also noticed that they tend to have high ratings. [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242615/how-can-i-get-junk-in-my-trunk?rq=1) is an example, but only the title is humorous. I have seen some others in the past, but I couldn't remember what they were about. If anyone wishes to add more examples, please feel free to.

Comment: I am not really sure what you're asking here. Like "how far is too far" with question titles?

Comment: I think the best answer here is that humour is acceptable when it does not impede on the quality of the question/answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to make the question funny, it's not going to be. The best question titles are accurate and descriptive - humor is a nice bonus, but it's certainly not more important than the question being clear and searchable. Forcing "funny" question titles doesn't do anyone any favors, and should be avoided. Sure, you might get those hot network question upvotes... but too often questions are edited after the fact to make the title "more funny". This should be avoided at all costs.